# What is needed to make the last else statement appear?

Tags: ruby

If the user were to input random letters instead of a number, "that is not a number" should be the output. It instead puts out "they can not come in" what do I need to change?

```
print "how old are you? "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

if age >= 21
  puts "They can come in"
elsif age < 21
  puts "they can not come in"
else 
  puts "that is not a number"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `to_i` on a `string` object you'll always get 0. So

```
print "how old are you? "
s_age = gets.chomp
if age.match /\A\d+\Z/
  age = s_age.to_i
  puts "They can come in" if age >= 21
  puts "They can not come in" if age < 21
else
  puts "That is not a number"
end
```

or

```
begin
  print "how old are you? "
  age = Integer gets.chomp # Integer(string) raise an exception if the parameter is not an integer
  puts "They can come in" if age >= 21
  puts "They can not come in" if age < 21
rescue
  puts "That is not a number"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do the check for whether or not it is a valid number beforehand. Your logic is flawed, as if they put in letters, then `gets.chomp.to_i` simply returns 0, which is technically less than `21`. In fact, it's really safer to not immediately convert to an integer straightaway, depending on how restrictive you want to be. So rather, do this:

```
age = gets.chomp.to_i
if age == 0 then puts "that is not a number" end
```

and then the rest of your code.
Not that this solution does not work with valid "age 0" answers, as 0 defaults to invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "How old are you? "
puts Integer(gets) >= 21 ? 'They can come in' : 'They can not come in' rescue puts 'Not a number'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can see is by adding a slight modification to the `elsif` condition:

```
print "how old are you? "
age = gets.chomp.to_i

if age >= 21
  puts "They can come in"
elsif age >= 0 && age < 21
  puts "they can not come in"
else 
  puts "that is not a number"
end
```